# Primality test for Mersenne numbers using the fourth Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, lucas-lehmer-test

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the claim given below?

Inspired by [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) I have formulated the following claim :

> Let $T_n(x)$ be [the nth Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind). Let $M_p=2^p-1$ such that $p$ is an odd prime. Let $S_i=T_4(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0=2$ . Then , $M_p$ is prime iff $S_{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod{M_p}$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1ijEOwjAMAPc8o5MtXKEENuMnZMrOQAhKpJZYbVTE7_HCdLrTqVw8uySBXZRw19ksj00Mn9qWAiY3Aet4DpQk9idoX3Itj-9eywFX8pSQIrKdJ_HIrr0gicTZk27tPWAyrGXCv-a-at_bsIT8A1SRJkc=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) .

I have verified this claim for all $p$ up to $10000$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is in fact equivalent to the Lucas Lehmer test. First of all because of $$f(f(x))=T_4(x)$$ with $$f(x)=2x^2-1$$ your test is equivalent to the following test :

If $$S_0=2$$ and $$S_{i+1}=f(S_i)$$ then $$2^p-1$$ is prime if and only if $$S_{p-1}\equiv -1\mod M_p$$

If we compare to Lucas-Lehmer, we have $$T_0=4$$ $$T_{i+1}=T_i^2-2$$ then the statement is that $$2^p-1$$ is prime if and only if $$T_{p-2} \equiv 0\mod M_p$$ which is equivalent to $$T_{p-1}\equiv -2\mod M_p$$

We can easily show $T_i=2S_i$ for all $i$ by considering $$x^2-2=2(2(\frac{x}{2})^2-1)$$ and from this the equivalence easily follows.